# Trato de usar un objeto Scanner para leer por teclado texto dentro de un do-while y me da error

Tags: java, while, scanner

No se por qué durante el segundo ciclo me marca un error durante la lectura de un objeto Scanner, espero que me puedan ayudar.

La solución la conozco. Es instanciar dentro del `do-while`, ahora. ¿Por qué ocurre ese error?

```
package ej619_2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ej619_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int tamano;
       char caracterRelleno;
       
       try
       {
           Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
           do
           {
               System.out.print("Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: ");
               tamano = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());
               System.out.print("Ingrese el caracter de relleno: ");
               caracterRelleno = entrada.next().charAt(0);
           }
           while(tamano <= 0);

           cuadradoDeAsteriscos(tamano, caracterRelleno);
       }
       catch (RuntimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
    
    public static void cuadradoDeAsteriscos(int tamano, char caracterRelleno)
    {
        for(int fila = 0; fila < tamano; fila++)
        {
            for(int columna = 0; columna < tamano; columna++)
            {
                System.out.print(caracterRelleno);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

La salida es el siguiente:

run:

Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: 0

Ingrese el caracter de relleno: #

Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: For input string: ""

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: "... _me marca un error_...". Los errores tienen información y esa información suele ser esencial para saber lo que pasa. Por favor, concreta ese error que dices que te _marca_.

Comment: El problema que veo es en la linea:   tamano = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine()); Que pasa si entrada.nextLine() no devuelve nada? El Integer.parseInt va a sonar.

Comment: Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: 0
Ingrese el caracter de relleno: Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: $
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at ej619_2.Ej619_2.main(Ej619_2.java:15)

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich , gracias. Si lo tengo claro, pero mas bien mi consulta es sobre lo detallado anteriormente. Espero que me puedas ayudar. Gracias!

Comment: @aydaroo Debes editar la pregunta y añadir los detalles que faltan. Por ejemplo, especifica que error muestra en pantalla (no lo agregues en comentario). En tu caso, debes capturar la excepción *NumberFormatException* con un *try-catch*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **¿Por qué ocurre ese error?**

El método `next()` lee el siguiente token completo de la entrada pero no incluye el salto de línea. Por ejemplo, si se ingresa el caracter de relleno `*` y se presiona `enter` el método `next()` devolverá `*` y lo asignará a la variable `caracterRelleno`. Hasta ahí todo bien. El problema es que al presionar `enter` se insertó un caracter invisible `\n` (el salto de línea) y ese caracter no fue leído por `next()` por lo tanto sigue en el buffer de entrada. Cuando se hace la siguiente iteración del `do while` el escaner `entrada` detecta que hay un caracter en el buffer y lo lee con `nextLine()`, luego intenta convertir el valor leído en un `Int` y ahí se produce el error, porque intenta convertir un `\n` en `Int`.

Por esa razón la solución podría ser usar `nextLine()` en lugar de `next()` para no dejar nada en el buffer de entrada.

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta.
El problema no es la línea que lee el caracter, es la línea de mas arriba, donde se lee el número entero. El salto de línea que molesta (donde se lee el número entero) es eliminada con el `Integer.parseInt()`, por cualquier cosa.
Si quieres, puedes comentar la linea que lee los caracteres y la impresión del cuadrado de caracteres y verás el mismo error.

Comment: Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: 0

Ingrese el caracter de relleno: Ingrese tamaño del cuadrado a dibujar: $
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at ej619_2.Ej619_2.main(Ej619_2.java:15)

Comment: Sí revisaste que cambiando `next()` por `nextLine()` se corrige el error, verdad?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt()` no elimina el salto de línea. El salto de línea lo elimina `nextLine()` y como ese salto de línea es el que te explicaba que no fue leído por `next()` entonces se retorna una cadena vacía que es la que produce la excepción en el `parseInt()`. Usar un `try/catch` no va a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Disculpa